# Setting read-only fields in a chained constructor

Tags: c#

I have a class with two read-only fields that are being set in the constructor. I have a derived class that would like to set these to *different* values in the constructor; however, trying to do so results in a CS1091 (A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer) error.

I don't see why this is - I *am* assigning to the fields in a constructor. Just not the one of the class where they're defined.

Is there some subtle syntax issue that I'm missing, or is this just not possible?

(There's ways around it if this isn't possible - probably a protected virtual property without a setter, and private readonly backing fields; syntactically it's not going to be as clean, however, so I wanted to avoid them if I can.)

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected readonly ushort OffsetRoutine;
    protected readonly ushort OffsetString;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.OffsetRoutine = this.GetWord(Addresses.Header.OffsetRoutine);
        this.OffsetString = this.GetWord(Addresses.Header.OffsetString);
    }

    protected ushort GetWord(byte address)
    {
        // Chosen by fair dice roll on a d100.
        return 42;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
        : base()
    {
        this.OffsetRoutine = 0;
        this.OffsetString = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are not providing a key detail - setting a `readonly` field is allowed ONLY in the declaration **OR a constructor of the same class**. This is just one of the differences between `readonly` and `const`. The `const` modifier does not allow you to set the field in a constructor - only in the declaration. So setting the `readonly` in a derived class is simply not allowed since the field is not in the same class. I assume you don't need workarounds as you seemed to know how to go about it if necessary, and there are other answers discussing that. From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx):

> When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to
>   the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the
>   declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

Just a few examples:

```
public class A
{
    protected const string constString = "Test";          //Allowed
    protected readonly string readonlyString = "Test";    //Allowed

    public A(){
      constString = "Test";      //Not allowed
      readonlyString = "Test";   //Allowed
    } 
}

public class B: A
{
    public B(){
      constString = "Test";      //Not allowed
      readonlyString = "Test";   //Not allowed
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it answered the question of what the syntax issue that I was missing was, rather than just offering a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible,  I think meaning of word readonly is clear enough.

Your question is not clear, but you probably want something like this:

```
private ushort _offsetRoutine;
private ushort _offsetString;

public BaseClass()
{
     _offsetRoutine= this.GetWord(Addresses.Header.OffsetRoutine);
     _offsetString= this.GetWord(Addresses.Header.OffsetString);
}

public ushort OffsetRoutine
{
    get { return _offsetRoutine;}
}

public ushort OffsetString
{
    get { return _offsetString;}
}
```

Now you can access `OffsetRoutine` `OffsetString`  but you can't change their value.

Comment: The meaning *seems* clear enough, but then the error says that I can only do write to it in a constructor. Which is what I was trying to do! :)

That's the solution that I was alluding to in my fourth paragraph, and so it's probably what I'm going to end up needing to do.

Comment: @AndrewTimson okay tell me if this not helping you I can delete it. Also why you want to use readonly when you want to change the value ...

Comment: No need to delete it. It shows a route that has the same effect, so unless there's some other insight that comes along I'll accept it as the answer.  
  
I don't want to change the value once it has been set, hence it being readonly. However, I want one value in the parent class and a different value in the child class. Your solution with the properties seems like it would achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Send the values into the constructor. You cannot call methods when setting a readonly.

This way works.

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        protected readonly ushort OffsetRoutine;
        protected readonly ushort OffsetString;

        public BaseClass(ushort value1, ushort value2)
        {
            OffsetRoutine = value1;
            OffsetString = value2;
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public DerivedClass(ushort value1, ushort value2)
            : base(value1, value2)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem isn't calling the methods from the base class - that works fine. (Code analysis will gripe if they're virtual, but it'll compile either way.) The problem is setting the values in the child class.

Comment: @AndrewTimson Sorry I missed that. I believe the edit will solve your problem.